# Angular 8 data binding stopped working on update

Tags: angular, data-binding

I updated my project to the latest version of Angular (both are in v8) and now data binding has stopped working in the View.

I've confirmed via the console that the properties are getting updated, but the template is not.

I've been researching this, tried another upgrade but no dice.

TypeScript:

```
import { Component,OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ProductService} from './product.service';
import { UnserializeService } from './unserialize.service';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { EnvService } from './env.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [ProductService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
  selectionList:Array<any> = []; 
  showThankYou = false;

// View now shows this default getting added, but no other added values after page initialization
  selectedOption = {
    name: "test",
    section_index: 0
  } ;

goToNextSection(){
   //set the data the will be used in the sidebar
   this.selectedOption['name'] = this.currentUserSelection.product_name;
   this.selectedOption['section_index'] = this.sectionIndex;
   this.selectionList.push(  this.selectedOption );  
    }

  goToThankYou(){
    this.spinner.show();
    var selectedOption = [];
    //set the data the will be used in the sidebar
    this.selectedOption['name'] = this.currentUserSelection.product_name;
    this.selectedOption['section_index'] = this.sectionIndex;
    this.selectionList.push(this.selectedOption);
    this.showThankYou = true;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<section id="side_menu" class="inline">
  <h2>Options</h2>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let selection of selectionList" class="selected-list">
      {{selection.name}} 
      <a href="#" (click)="editSection(selection.section_index )">Edit</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section id="main_form" class="inline">

  <app-options-sections
  *ngIf="!showThankYou" >
  </app-options-sections>

  <app-thank-you-section
  *ngIf="showThankYou">
  </app-thank-you-section>

</section>

<ngx-spinner></ngx-spinner>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I expect that selectionList will add an li to the ul every time either of those functions run. Console.log is showing that the values are being placed in the property, but the view doesn't change.

Also, when go to than you is set to TRUE, app-thank-you-section will be used instead of app-options-sections. But that doesn't work either (but I've verified that values are changing. )

Comment: where do you declare and populate `selectedOption`?

Comment: Sorry, updated code above. I initially had it declared in goToNextSection() as just a var, but moved it up as a prop when it stopped working, thinking that might get something going. (This was also prior to writing the goToThankYou func.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've declared incorrect type of `selectedOption = [];`. It is a type of an array. However, you need to declare it as an object:

```
selectedOption = {};
```

because in loop you want to show a value of key:

```
<li *ngFor="let selection of selectionList" class="selected-list">
  {{selection.name}}  <!-- here you are showing value of key `name` -->
  <a href="#" 
     (click)="editSection(selection.section_index )"><!-- here you are passing value of key `section_index` -->
     Edit
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch, but it's still not working. I've changed it over to being an object, and even haveing default params to begin with. It will display the default params if I add the push() to the constructor, but not anything that is added to it in the goToNextSection(), even when displaying in the console shows that all of the properties are getting updated correctly.

Comment: @anthony_ksand could you create an example at stackblitz.com?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdmz2q
I added all of the code for the relevant files as well as some test data. There are some AJAX calls that are going on to get the actual data.

Comment: @anthony_ksand  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdmz2q your stackblitz example is not working. There is an error `Error in /turbo_modules/@angular/compiler@8.0.0/bundles/compiler.umd.js (2479:21)`.

Comment: @anthony_ksand just create a work example where you can reproduce your error. This example should not make any API queries. Just create a simple array with necessary code without unnecessary code

Comment: Yea, I know - there are a lot of moving parts to this..... I was able to resolve this by moving all of my subtemplate code into the parent template. Not exactly what I wanted, and certainly not as neat, but it works and the deadline is approaching. But thank you for all of your help!!!!!

Comment: @anthony_ksand I am glad that if it was helpful to you! :) [what should I do when somebody makes an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by taking all of my code in the sub-templates and place it in the parent template and making creative use of ngIf. Exactly what I didn't want to do, but at least it's working for now.